Informix C++ Client SDK multi-thread connection issue
I'm developing an application multi-thread that needs to connect to an Informix DB.
I'm working with the CSDK 4.50 and C++ libraries.
I'm encountering issues with the connection. I didn't find the way in which initialize a different connection for every thread.
Here is a simple snippet of code to replicate my issues:
#include <it.h>

int main()
{
    const constexpr int nthreads = 10;
    std::thread t[nthreads];
  
    for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i) {
        t[i] = std::thread(printArt, i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; ++i) {
        t[i].join();
    }

    return 0;
}

void printArt(int i)
{
    ITDBInfo dbinfo;
    dbinfo.SetDatabase("eda");
    
    ITConnection conn;
    conn.Open(dbinfo);
    
    if (conn.Error()) {
        return;
    }

    conn.SetTransaction(ITConnection::Begin);
    
    ITCursor cursor(conn);
    
    if (!cursor.Prepare("select first 1 * from a_table;")) {
        conn.SetTransaction(ITConnection::ABORT);
        return;
    }

    if (!cursor.Open()) {
        conn.SetTransaction(ITConnection::ABORT);
        return;
    }

    ITRow* row = nullptr;
    while ((row = cursor.NextRow()) != nullptr) {
        string col0 = row->Column(0)->Printable().Data();
        string col1 = row->Column(1)->Printable().Data();

        cout << "[" << i << "] " << col0 << " | " << col1 << endl;

        row->Release();
    }

    conn.SetTransaction(ITConnection::Commit);

    conn.Close();

    return;
}

The result of this execution is undefined: sometimes it goes ahead until the end, sometimes it crashes with a core dump.
When the program doesn't crash, it seems that only one query has a result and prints it. The expected result is to see 1 line printed from every query (thread).
I've linked the th prefixed libraries as suggested in this answer, the result is always the one described above.
Where is my mistake?
How can I use a multi-threaded programming with these C++ Informix libraries?
I know that with ESQL-C (the C-library) the way in which achieve this is using a different session-id for each connection (thread).
Is there an analogous feature in the C++ library?

Update:
I use only one #include <it.h> that call every .h that informix needs. The libraries used for building in g++ are the dynamic ones:  -l thsql -l thasf -l thgen -l thos -l ifgls -l ifglx -l thdmi -l thc++.
Client Platform: Alma Linux 9.4 X86_64 (RHEL9.4 compatible)

This code doesn't even compile, and not only because of missing headers for ITDBInfo or ITConnection.

The design of the C++ interface library predates C++98.  Ideally, you would not be using it.  I've been advocating for it to be removed from the Informix CSDK product for a number of years (more than a decade), so far without success.  I think you'd do better with a wrapper around ESQL/C code (written in C, linked with the thread-safe libraries).

Please update the code in your question to include the headers and any other information that is currently omitted.  Which platform are you on?  How are you compiling and linking the code?  If you're using the thread-safe C++IF, I believe each call to conn.Open() should provide a separate connection.  (Indeed, each separate conn.Open() should provide a separate connection in non-threaded code too.)  The manual is at Informix Object Interface for C++ Guide, as I'm sure you're aware.

@JonathanLeffler thanks for your interest, I updated the questions with other details as you requested.
Of course I already read the official documentation of the C++ Client library, but I didn't find any response to my question.
